# Python parallel execution slower than serial, even with batches

Tags: python, performance, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a txt file with several hundreds of thousands of strings, each on a new line.
I need to create a list with an element for each string. Each of these elements must be a list that contains ordered substrings of the original string. The length of the substrings is a k given.
For example with the following file content

```
ABCDEFH
EJDNOENDE
DEMD
```

And `k = 3` I get

```
[
  [ABC, BCD, CDE, DEF, EFH],
  [EJD, JDN, DNO, NOE, OEN, END, NDE],
  [DEM, ]
]
```

Consider that generally the file is long several hundreds of thousands of lines and the average length of each line is 150. k is almost always above 10, even up to 50.

My code in series (that works) is:

```py
def build_k_mers(reads: list[str], k: int) -> list[list[str]]:
  return [[read[i : i + k] for i in range(len(read) - k + 1)] for read in reads]
```

Since building each sublist is an independent process I thought of parallelizing. My first attempt was:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def build_k_mers_helper(args: tuple[str, int]) -> list[str]:
  read, k = args
  k_mers = [read[i : i + k] for i in range(len(read) - k + 1)]
  return k_mers
    
def build_k_mers_parallel(reads: list[str], k: int) -> list[list[str]]:
  with Pool(cpu_count()) as pool:
    k_mers = pool.map(build_k_mers_helper, [(read, k) for read in reads])
  return k_mers
```

But this code would take slightly more time than the serial one. I thought it might have been because Python (in particular Jupyter Notebook) uses only one process anyway, and creating multiple processes would only add the switching context time. However, to test this, I opened Resource Monitor and I saw all cores of my CPU running at 100% during the script execution.
Seeing this I thought that maybe it is indeed able to use multiple cores, so I thought that maybe since each `build_k_mers_helper` is quite fast (just a list comprehension on a short string) still switching context for each process that starts and terminates almost immediately slows down everything.

My second attempt then was:

```py
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

def build_k_mers_helper_batch(args: tuple[list[str], int]) -> list[list[str]]:
  batch, k = args
  return [[read[i : i + k] for i in range(len(read) - k + 1)] for read in batch]
    
def build_k_mers_parallel_batch(reads: list[str], k: int) -> list[list[str]]:
  seqs = [read for read in reads]
  step = int(len(seqs) / cpu_count()) or 1
  with Pool(cpu_count()) as pool:
    k_mers_batches = pool.map(build_k_mers_helper_batch, [(seqs[i : i + step], k) for i in range(0, len(seqs), step)])
  print('Terminated batches')
  return [k_mers for batch in k_mers_batches for k_mers in batch]
```

To avoid the "too many context switching" problem. Basically instead of creating a process for each line, I create a process for each batch of lines such that each CPU core (each process) takes care of the same amount of batches and very few switching context are needed (indeed only setupping the processes and terminating them should be needed).

This attempt still did not manage to get better performance than the serial one, and was even a tiny bit slower than the previous attempt.

What am I doing wrong or how could I actually improve execution time by parallelizing?

My system has 64GB of RAM and an Intel Core i7-12700H (`cpu_count()` returns `20`).

My benchmark code is:

```py
from kmers import build_k_mers_parallel, build_k_mers_parallel_batch, build_k_mers
from timeit import Timer

setup = '''
from kmers import build_k_mers_parallel, build_k_mers_parallel_batch, build_k_mers

with open('filename.txt') as file:
    reads = file.readlines()
'''

print(min(Timer('build_k_mers(reads, 50)', setup).repeat(3, 100)))
```

Of course changing `filename` and the function called in the timeit Timer according to what I was benchmarking.
I tested with the setups below, keeping `k = 50` across all tests.

|  | number of lines | serial | parallel | batch parallel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| #0 | 500k | 0m 14s | 0m 15s | 0m 16s |
| #1 | 1M | 0m 19s | 0m 21s | 0m 23s |
| #2 | 2M | 0m 27s | 0m 33s | 0m 36s |
| #3 | 3M | 0m 38s | 0m 43s | 0m 45s |
| #4 | 4M | 0m 43s | 0m 57s | 1m 00s |
| #5 | 5M | 0m 54s | 1m 10s | 1m 15s |

Bigger files would start using the disk as swap space, slowing everything down considerably thus distorting the benchmark.

Comment: If you're using multithreading, you're still going to be affected by [GlobalInterpreterLock](https://realpython.com/python-gil/). Multiprocessing doesn't have that issue, though; that's how to do true parallelism in Python.

Comment: @RandomDavis isn't it what I'm doing by using Pool from multiprocessing? Just to be clear I will edit my question with the imports I used

Comment: Now that you have included your full [mre], I can see that that's what you were doing, but before you shared it, it was ambiguous since you didn't share the import statements.

Comment: How much memory does your computer have? You are building up your results in memory, and the data resulting from this algorithm will be quite sizeable. Assuming a 1,000,000 line file with an average line length of 150 and a k of 20, the resulting data will be 3.6GB (not including the pointers used for the data structures etc.). If you run out of memory during the algorithm you will swap memory out to disk instead, which will decrease performance significantly.

Comment: On my 8GB machine I was able to process a 500,000 line file in about 17 seconds (in serial), but a 1,000,000 line file slowed it down to a crawl.

Comment: @JackTaylor I have 64GB of RAM. I can confirm that files too large start using the disk, around 2M lines is currently the most I can run before using the disk. Nevertheless, with files with less than 2M lines I still don't get any performance improvement, the parallel batch algorithm takes slightly more than the serial one (30s vs 45s)

Comment: I will add my benchmark setups and results in the question for better clarity.

Comment: Hmm, why did you delete your answer? Is it wrong somehow?

Comment: @KellyBundy yeah. While it was true that I was using Seq instead of strings, I changed my code to use strings everywhere, also in the serial execution. Now again the parallels take more than the serial.

Comment: @JackTaylor I updated my question with more info. I also managed to load files up to 5M lines by avoiding saving the result in a variable (this saves RAM since I'm using Jupyter Notebook).

Answer (score 2):

Multiprocessing lets you use more cores, but its not a panacea- the extra processes don't share memory. This means that when you call pool.map(), what is actually happening in the background-

1. Your app creates a work and a results Queue object
2. It forks itself N times. In the workers, they run a function to listen to the work Queue to get "tasks", execute your function, and send the results back to the results Queue.
3. Your original process executes your iterator, sends each object to the queue, reads the results from the results queue as they come back, and builds the final result set.

Every time an object goes over a Queue between processes, it has to get serialized (by pickle) - since the programs don't share memory anymore, they can only send bytes.

This means that to use multiprocessing for a task, you are adding two serialization steps and a coordination task to rebuild the final result. This can be a big win if the work that is happening in each task is intense- but in this case, the serialization is as much work as the actual work, if not more.

There are ways to work around this. Just a few-

1. You could use a library like numpy that is designed to release the GIL, letting you use threads to do the work in parallel.
2. You could use shared memory - write the input data into a shared memory object and pass the location of the object to the child processes instead of the data itself. Much less serialization, probably more complicated code.
3. You could do the same, but with the already existing data. Instead of passing the string to the subprocess, pass the file location each one should work on, and let each child process read the file. This could get hairy with a single file and many child processes, but is actually the best solution usually, because you can change your data storage to match the pattern. Store many small files instead of one giant one, and let each child process read one file. This is usually the best approach to do distributed computing.

Comment: I don't think the input is the problem. The output is much bigger than the input. Can the output be optimized with memory sharing (or some other way) as well?

Comment: Of course, everything I mentioned about input can apply to output as well. However, something like "using many small files" for the output part will mean that your head process will now have to open and read many small files. Now you start to look at the "reduce" portion of mapreduce, and have child processes to turn the many small output files into a few larger output files, reducing the work the head process has to do. The problem is really that you're dealing with a toy problem to learn how to do this stuff, even though these approaches don't really help with such easy workloads.

Comment: [Test](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=dY9BDoIwEEX3PcXshCgNmJgYE05CiCFQYCy0TVsWnsUNG72TF_AcDhaW7mby3_w___Eyd99rNc_PybfJ-f3B0WjrwWAtB8HWzVaq0eO2OW9RdYxZUTWQw27HbxpVFCBe9xpr4aJA8crViNdBeC-sO4DMs1Max4xJujymbHCehmKxKhAugLAHWUKrLY2oluRORIMge0JiSEASkcUlY4b8_U8Kz_JmGo0LHCX8kSmQ1NB2Lb2V_wI) results: Pickling a string of 150 random letters took 165 bytes. Pickling the list of substrings of length 20 took 3029 bytes.

Comment: Oh, somehow I managed to misread that part about the files. Yes, that way obviously also works for the output. And if the output files can be purely concatenated, without having to be unpickled and repickled, it's probably fast. But yeah, they might not even have to do that in their actual task, whatever that is, presumably not just to produce a large collection of strings but computing some smaller result from them. For example if they wanted to find the substring with the largest sha256 value, that would have small output (and increase computation, making input costs less relevant).

Comment: To be clear, the size isn't the important part. The cutoff is "time to do a unit of the work" vs "time to serialize/deserialize the input/output to send that work to another process". When the first unit is very small "run split() on a short string", it will be virtually impossible to get the second unit small enough to benefit. This is really why libraries like numpy and pandas exist, to work around the python limitation of parallelizing simple tasks being really hard without writing c code.

Comment: How would I go for number 2? I tried creating a global shared list variable with a manager, but of course when I try to access it from the helper function it says that it's not defined.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.shared_memory.html

Comment: @PaulBecotte Sure, but the size is correlated to the time to (de)serialize.

Comment: Either I don't understand how or I just can't use SharedMemory (and ShareableList) for what I need. While I can easily share the values of k and step, it becomes problematic when I'm trying to share seqs and k_mers. First of all k_mers should be a list of lists, but the list type is not supported by ShareableList which means I would need to serialize and deserialize myself the list (kind of defeating the whole purpose). Anyway I tried instead of storing a list of lists to store a list of string formed by the joined substring with ',', but it takes waaay more (more than 6m for the 500k test).